# Unity Android build crashes on start due Proguard

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, proguard, crashlytics, facebook-unity-sdk

A development build works fine, but when I try a release build, it crashes immediately on start due to the `Proguard`.

I installed `Crashlytics` to try getting any error but it does not show any error (crashlytics works).

Might be important to add:

Just added `Firebase` and `Facebook SDK`.

How should the `proguard.txt` file look like?

Thank you in advance.